# Is there a command line tool to compare .tiff files visually (pixel by pixel)?

Tags: java, command-line, compare, tiff

Is there a way to compare .tiff files pixel by pixel with a command line tool?

For example:

**Input:** *tool image1.tiff image2.tiff*

**Output:** *True (bool) (if same), False (bool) (if differences are found)*

Maybe also a Java code/tool?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you only want a true/false response, just calculate and compare the md5 or something.

Comment: It isn't clear whether the intention is to compare the _files_, for which operating system tools like diff and md5sum are likely to be appropriate, or compare the actual image data. And if the intention is to compare the image data, what happens if, for example, colours are encoded differently in the different files? Do we need to check for the image data being identical (so far as that is possible), or within some threshold. FWIW I can provide some Java code that will read a TIFF into an array of RGB pixel values; but you'd still need to work out how to do the actual comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ImageMagick for [comparing images](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php). According to its [documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php), it supports TIFF files too.

Command for comparing images:

```
compare -verbose -metric mae pic1.tiff pic2.tiff difference.png
```

For identical images it will print only zeros:

```
Channel distortion: MAE
    red: 0 (0)
    green: 0 (0)
    blue: 0 (0)
    alpha: 0 (0)
    all: 0 (0)
```

For different images it will print non-zero values, for example:

```
Channel distortion: MAE
    red: 2282.91 (0.034835)
    green: 1853.99 (0.0282901)
    blue: 2008.67 (0.0306503)
    all: 1536.39 (0.0234439)
```

Or if the size of images are different, it will complain about that:

```
image widths or heights differ
```

You can use these outputs to generate a true/false value for yourself. ([Here are some ideas.](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=12618))

Comment: In my test, the output of `compare` on two multi-page TIFF files was useless. Probably, `compare` was not meant for comparing two multi-page TIFF files pagewise. *Pagewise* means: for each page number  between 1 and the minimum (or maximum) of the page counts of the two files, page  of file 1 should be compared with page  of file 2, and the results of comparison should be visually presented in the output document.